# How do I get my java program to read Japanese (Unicode encoding) from a text file?

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, text-files

I have followed an example program from the book "Head First Java", chapter 14 page 448-459

Here's a link to the book online though Google Books: [Head First Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=uIVJiAPlBq0C&pg=PA448&lpg=PA448&dq=java%20flash%20cards%20text%20file&source=bl&ots=9gljIhZkxQ&sig=vgClQ01VJJuOJZN654JeHRZa5eg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_wrUUvbsKOGzyAGVzYCQBw&ved=0CGEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=java%20flash%20cards%20text%20file&f=false)

I made sure that I had Japanese installed as a viewing language on my OS (Windows 7) and I of course have the Japanese IME in order to type in Japanese in the first place.

I even saved the text file with a unicode encoding.

I'm sure this has something to do with the code because it works properly with only English words.

Thank you!

The program consists of 3 classes.

```
package chap14;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class QuizCardReader {

private JTextArea display;
private JTextArea answer;
private ArrayList cardList;
private QuizCard currentCard;
private Iterator cardIterator;
private JFrame frame;
private JButton nextButton;
private boolean isShowAnswer;


public static void main (String[] args) {
   QuizCardReader qReader = new QuizCardReader();
   qReader.go();
}

public void go() {

    frame = new JFrame("Quiz Card Player");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    Font bigFont = new Font("sanserif", Font.BOLD, 24);

    display = new JTextArea(9,20);
    display.setFont(bigFont);
    display.setLineWrap(true);
    display.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    display.setEditable(false);

    JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(display);
    qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
          ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
          ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    nextButton = new JButton("Show Question");

    mainPanel.add(qScroller);
    mainPanel.add(nextButton);
    nextButton.addActionListener(new NextCardListener());
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

    JMenuItem loadMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Load card set");

    loadMenuItem.addActionListener(new OpenMenuListener());

    fileMenu.add(loadMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
    frame.setSize(500,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);        
  } 


  public class NextCardListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
      if (isShowAnswer) {

         display.setText(currentCard.getAnswer());
         nextButton.setText("Next Card");
         isShowAnswer = false;
      } else {

         if (cardIterator.hasNext()) {

            showNextCard();

          } else {

             display.setText("That was last card");
             nextButton.disable();
          }
       }
    }
   }


  public class OpenMenuListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
         JFileChooser fileOpen = new JFileChooser();
         fileOpen.showOpenDialog(frame);
         loadFile(fileOpen.getSelectedFile());
    }
  }

  private void loadFile(File file) {
  cardList = new ArrayList();
  try {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     String line = null;
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        makeCard(line);
     }
     reader.close();

  } catch(Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("couldn't read the card file");
      ex.printStackTrace();
  }


 cardIterator = cardList.iterator();
 showNextCard();
}

 private void makeCard(String lineToParse) {

  StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(lineToParse, "/");
  if (parser.hasMoreTokens()) {
     QuizCard card = new QuizCard(parser.nextToken(), parser.nextToken());
     cardList.add(card);
  }
}

 private void showNextCard() {
    currentCard = (QuizCard) cardIterator.next();
    display.setText(currentCard.getQuestion());
    nextButton.setText("Show Answer");
    isShowAnswer = true;
 }
 }
```

Here is the second class.

```
package chap14;
import java.io.*;

public class QuizCard implements Serializable {

 private String uniqueID;
 private String category;
 private String question;
 private String answer;
 private String hint;

 public QuizCard(String q, String a) {
     question = q;
     answer = a;
}


 public void setUniqueID(String id) {
    uniqueID = id;
 }

 public String getUniqueID() {
    return uniqueID;
 }

 public void setCategory(String c) {
    category = c;
 }

 public String getCategory() {
     return category;
 }

 public void setQuestion(String q) {
    question = q;
 }

 public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
 }

 public void setAnswer(String a) {
    answer = a;
 }

 public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
 }

 public void setHint(String h) {
    hint = h;
 }

 public String getHint() {
    return hint;
 }

}
```

And the third class

```
package chap14;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class QuizCardBuilder {

private JTextArea question;
private JTextArea answer;
private ArrayList cardList;
private JFrame frame;



public static void main (String[] args) {
   QuizCardBuilder builder = new QuizCardBuilder();
   builder.go();
}

public void go() {

    frame = new JFrame("Quiz Card Builder");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  // title bar
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    Font bigFont = new Font("sanserif", Font.BOLD, 24);
    question = new JTextArea(6,20);
    question.setLineWrap(true);
    question.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    question.setFont(bigFont);

    JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(question);
    qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
              ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
              ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    answer = new JTextArea(6,20);
    answer.setLineWrap(true);
    answer.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    answer.setFont(bigFont);

    JScrollPane aScroller = new JScrollPane(answer);
    aScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
              ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    aScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
              ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next Card");
    cardList = new ArrayList();
    JLabel qLabel = new JLabel("Question:");
    JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Answer:");

    mainPanel.add(qLabel);
    mainPanel.add(qScroller);
    mainPanel.add(aLabel);
    mainPanel.add(aScroller);
    mainPanel.add(nextButton);
    nextButton.addActionListener(new NextCardListener());
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");

    JMenuItem saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
    newMenuItem.addActionListener(new NewMenuListener());
    saveMenuItem.addActionListener(new SaveMenuListener());

    fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
    fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
    frame.setSize(500,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);        
 }


 public class NextCardListener implements ActionListener {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
      QuizCard card = new QuizCard(question.getText(), answer.getText());
      cardList.add(card);
      clearCard();

    }
 }

 public class SaveMenuListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
       QuizCard card = new QuizCard(question.getText(), answer.getText());
       cardList.add(card);

       JFileChooser fileSave = new JFileChooser();
       fileSave.showSaveDialog(frame);
       saveFile(fileSave.getSelectedFile());
     }
  }

  public class NewMenuListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
       cardList.clear();
       clearCard();           
     }
  }


  private void clearCard() {
     question.setText("");
     answer.setText("");
     question.requestFocus();
  }

  private void saveFile(File file) {

   try {
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
      Iterator cardIterator = cardList.iterator();
      while (cardIterator.hasNext()) {
         QuizCard card = (QuizCard) cardIterator.next();
         writer.write(card.getQuestion() + "/");
         writer.write(card.getAnswer() + "\n");
      }
     writer.close();


   } catch(IOException ex) {
       System.out.println("couldn't write the cardList out");
       ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

The errors I get when I try to get the program to read Japanese from a text file:

```
couldn't read the card file
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
at chap14.QuizCardReader.makeCard(QuizCardReader.java:122)
at chap14.QuizCardReader.loadFile(QuizCardReader.java:104)
at chap14.QuizCardReader.access$8(QuizCardReader.java:98)
at chap14.QuizCardReader$OpenMenuListener.actionPerformed(QuizCardReader.java:94)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What are you currently using to read the file? You can probably set the charset.

Comment: Please give us some code to look at. Without it, it makes it harder to help and understand you

Comment: Are you trying to display the japanese characters using sysout on console?

Comment: Oh wow....sorry. I had to submit this hurriedly >.< Let me post the code...

Comment: @Juned Ahsan, I'm trying to get Japanese to be read from a text file and outputted onto the screen. I have the text file encoded correctly. I'm not sure how to change this in the code however :/

Comment: This is a great introduction on the subject: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

should be

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

`FileReader` is an old utility class with no option to set the encoding. And that tripped you. The same holds for FileWriter that should use an OutputStreamWriter with a FileOutputStream and an encoding.

Whether this helps with the scanner, still is to see.

```
StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(lineToParse, "/");
if (parser.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String q = parser.nextToken();
    if (parser.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String a = parser.nextToken();
        QuizCard card = new QuizCard(q, a);
        cardList.add(card);
    }
}
```

or

```
String[] qa = lineToParse.split("/", 2);
if (qa.length == 2) {
    QuizCard card = new QuizCard(qa[0], aq[1]);
    cardList.add(card);
}
```

The latter would split "Kiom?/3 / 4" into `{"Kiom", "3 / 4"}` because of the `split(-, 2)`.

Comment: When I implemented you Buffered reader fix I got these errors.

Comment: couldn't read the card file
java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
 at chap14.QuizCardReader.makeCard(QuizCardReader.java:145)
 at chap14.QuizCardReader.loadFile(QuizCardReader.java:109)
 at chap14.QuizCardReader.access$8(QuizCardReader.java:101)
 at chap14.QuizCardReader$OpenMenuListener.actionPerformed(QuizCardReader.java:97)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: However, after I implemented the string tokenizer you posted it removed all errors but the Japanese still would not display correctly.

Comment: Are you sure about the encoding? The free programmers editor [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org) can switch encodings.

Comment: AH Nevermind! I changed the encoding from Unicode to UTF-8 after I implemented your fixes! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make code less cluttered, one can use [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)-related functionality that is available starting from Java 1.8:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class GenjiMonogatariReader{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream("源氏物語.txt"), "UTF-8")))
        {
            br.lines()
              .forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

The 源氏物語.txt file should be UTF-8 encoded in this particular example. Modify charset's name as needed.

Do keep in mind, though, that in order to view the text in console (I'm talking about the **cmd.exe** window), the system must support the Japanese language. If it doesn't, the output will most likely be garbled. Even changing the default [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) with `Locale.setDefault(Locale.JAPANESE);` won't help.

On the other hand, running the above code from inside an IDE such as NetBeans (in my case it's ver.8.1) gives completely satisfactory results.